# how to check for blank? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following

```
  session[:info] = {
    id: params[:id],
    description: params[:description], 
    blahblas: params[:blahblah] 
  }
```

what is the most efficient way to check if any one of session[:info][key] is blank? or empty to be more precise .Thank you

Comment: please make your question more clear..if am not wrong you mean to ask if any one of the session[:info] key is nil or not??

Comment: yes ...sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
session[:info].select{|k,v|v.blank?}
```

Comment: this solution is wat I was about to post, its simple and appropriate...or it can be `session[:info].select{|k,v|v.present?}`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
session[:info].key("")
```

which will return the first key it finds with a blank value.  If none of the values are blank it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
session[:info].inject(false) {|blank, (k,v)| blank ? blank : v.empty?}
```